# Bootstrap radio buttons inside my asp.net core mvc are not selectable

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, radio-button

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc core web application to show 2 radio buttons:-

```
<div class="form-group">
                      
                        <label class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label><br/>
                       
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"> 
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" value="true"  class="custom-control-input" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" value="false" class="custom-control-input"/>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">No</label>
                        </div>

</div>
```

which will generates the following markup:-

```
                <label class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">Are you currently ...?</label><br>
               
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio"> 
                <input type="radio" value="true" class="custom-control-input" name="SubmissionQuestionSubmission[0].Answer" id="SubmissionQuestionSubmission_0d__Answer">
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" value="false" class="custom-control-input" id="SubmissionQuestionSubmission_0__Answer" name="SubmissionQuestionSubmission[0].Answer">
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold">No</label>
                </div>
```

but the radio button i got will not be select-able (as-if they are disabled),, any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of bootstrap 4?

Comment: @Ben Sampica yes 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `for` in label to bind the `id` of input,and the id cannot be repeated.
Here is a demo worked:
Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestRadio()
        {
            Submission s = new Submission();
            List<SubmissionQuestion> sqs = new List<SubmissionQuestion> { new SubmissionQuestion { Question="question1"},new SubmissionQuestion { Question="question2"}, new SubmissionQuestion { Question = "question3" } };
            List<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> sqss = new List<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> { new SubmissionQuestionSubmission { Answer = true }, new SubmissionQuestionSubmission { Answer = false }, new SubmissionQuestionSubmission { Answer = true } };
            s.SubmissionQuestion = sqs;
            s.SubmissionQuestionSubmission = sqss;
            return View(s);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestRadio(Submission s) {
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@model Submission
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "TestRadio";
}

<h1>TestRadio</h1>
<form method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.SubmissionQuestion.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">


            <label class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold">@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label><br />

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer, "true", new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "true_" + @i })
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold" for="true_@i">Yes</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer, "false", new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "false_" + @i })
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="color: #7e7e7e;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold" for="false_@i">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Result:
[image]